# expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router

My Code as it is, I don't know where my error

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: %s.%s%s, undefined,  You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

app.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Navigator,
} from 'react-native';
import Movies from './Movies';

const RouteMapper = (route, navigator) => {
  if (route.name === 'movies') {
    return <Movies navigator={navigator} />;
  }
};

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Navigator
        // Default to movies route
        initialRoute={{ name: 'movies' }}
        // Use FloatFromBottom transition between screens
        configureScene={(route, routeStack) => Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromBottom}
        // Pass a route mapper functions
        renderScene={RouteMapper}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Movies.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  ScrollView,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import { movies } from './data';

export default class Movies extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <ScrollView>
          {movies.map((movie, index) => <Text>{movie.title}</Text>)}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: "You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports."

Answer (score 1):

You likely forgot to return jsx or a value other than `undefined` which is the default return of every function in JavaScript.

By my guess (since I don't know what is in other components) the error is from  `RouteMapper` which does a conditional return without a default return for if condition fails. You might want to return `null` as the default return of this component.

If this doesn't fix trace the rendered components and check if they all have a return statement that is not either implicitly or explicitly `undefined`