# Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object

Tags: reactjs

I wanna to implement react-background-slider and doens't work i dont know why :(

ERROR:

```
react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:87 Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
```

MY CODE:

```
import BackgroundSlider from "react-background-slider";

import slider1 from "../../../assets/background-page1.jpg";
import slider2 from "../../../assets/background-page2.jpg";
import slider4 from "../../../assets/background-page3.jpg";

const Slider = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <BackgroundSlider
        images={[slider1, slider2, slider4]}
        duration={10}
        transition={2}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: are you sure that `Slider` is the component throwing that error?

Comment: react_devtools_backend.js:4026 Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check your code at Slider.jsx:12.

Comment: I think you didn't export this component or didn't import it correctly, see this https://stackoverflow.com/q/63133478/18457414

Comment: SOLUTION: version 3.0.0 for react-background-slider doesnt work. need to impmenet 2.0.0 and it's working!